# Invertible positive elements

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In a $C^*$-algebra ${\cal A}$, I know that $a\in {\cal A}_+$ if and only if $a=x^*x$ for some $x\in {\cal A}$.

**Question**: If we know that $a$ is also invertible, can we choose $x$ to be invertible? It certainly is true for matrices.

Comment: Short answer is "yes". If $a$ is positive, you can choose $x=x^*=\sqrt{a}$, which is invertible when $a$ is. How much sense that makes to you probably depends on what stage of your C*-journey you are at though.

Comment: So for that choice of $x$, is it because the spectrum of $x$ related to $a$?

Comment: You could put it that way, so by the spectral mapping theorem for the continuous functional calculus the spectrum of $\sqrt{a}$ is the square root of the spectrum of $a$, hence doesn't contain zero. It would be simpler to exhibit a left and right inverse for $x$ though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@MikeF's comment is certainly the default answer to your question, but here is an argument which does not need square roots.

If $a$ is invertible and positive, then it also has these properties relative to the commutative C*-algebra generated by $a$ and $1$ (can you prove this?).

Therefore you may find $x$ inside that subalgebra, and hence $x$ and $x^*$  commute.

From the expression $a=x^*x$ you deduce that $x$ is left-invertible, and from $a=xx^*$, that $x$ is right-invertible.  It then follows that $x$ is invertible.